# Anime where a woman knocked into a window leaves Japanese characters with her blood

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, anime

There was a scene where a random woman was knocked onto a window, and as she slid down, she wrote Japanese symbols with her blood. There were also scenes where a guy said phrases that allowed him to channel something out of his palms. And as odd as it sounds, there was a scene where this woman met an old lady in a house and the old woman became some demon, making the younger woman float in air and molest her in some way. The last scene I can remember was that same woman who was molested was rescued, and she looked up to see a body with blood dripping from the ceiling, and the man who rescued her made her look away and had her covered in some sheets.

Comment: In what year did you saw it/Animation quality/Happens on earth?/Is there an MC?/Story happens in present or is a history setting?

Comment: Any descriptions on the characters. Hair color, day, night, why type of monster was it.  Thinkgs like that help out.